# Show overlay view above long scrollview to fill screen, when clicked on button at bottom of scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scrollview, which is a bit long and easily goes beyond the screen height. Now at the bottom of the scrollview, there is a button and on the click of that button I perform some actions. While those actions are completed, I want to show an overlay mask, that fills the screen.

OverlayLayout

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ImageView></ImageView>
  <TextView>Loading...</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ScrollView layout looks as

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>Main content</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want that the overlay mask is rendered on the top of LinearLayout within ScrollView with respect to the screen and not the parent ScrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScrollView can have only one child. What I would suggest doing is this

In your layout file

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout>Main content</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay_mask"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView></ImageView>
        <TextView>Loading...</TextView>
   </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

in your code get the LinearLayout view using findViewById() and on the button onClick set the visibility of the LinearLayout to `VISIBLE` and when your actions are done i.e. when you need the overlay mask to be gone just set the LinearLayout's visibility to be `GONE`. The `android:clickable` property will make sure that when your overlay mask is shown it will eat up all the touch events. The `android:background` property will apply a translucent black overlay effect.

Comment: This part is fine, its something that I have implemented. But the catch here is that the second LinearLayout(overlay_mask) with height, width set as match_parent will overlay over entire scrollview. Now, if I set android:gravity=center in overlay mask, due to the height of the overlay_mask that center will be somewhere outside the screen area. I don't want to set height,width to match_parent but only the visible screen area, so that loading image comes in the center of the screen

Comment: check the update in the answer. Should solve the issue you are having.

Comment: yes this seems workable, I am not sure if its a good design pattern. I am a bit new to android, not entirely sure as to what good design patterns are. But as I said, it seems workable and will do for now. Thanks.

Comment: Cool.. don't worry there is nothing wrong with this design. This has flexibility for adding animations, and working through code and is not cluttered plus there are no extra layouts or views that are being inflated. So as fas as the xml goes there is no problem with it.